# Execution failed for task ':compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to build the app (using ionic2 cordova)

```
ionic cordova build android
```

so an error occur :

```
D:\Projects\IPA\IPA004001_Mobile\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:851: error: cannot find symbol
                        FileUtils filePlugin = (FileUtils) pm.getPlugin("File");

Execution failed for task ':compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

these plugins i'm using :

```
"cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": "^2.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.2.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
```

i tried to delete **cordova-plugin-file-transfer** and then build the app , it successes. but i need this plugins so what should I do. They seems there incompatible versions of plugins with android-cordova but I tried many versions nothing success.

Comment: Did you tried by updating cordova-android to 6.4.0 ? seems file transfer plugin incompatible with 6.3.0

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies i tried and i got this error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\jsleiman\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n83
9fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

in platform/android build.gradle i change this:

```
com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
```

to

```
com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"
```

and in project.properties
this :

```
com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
```

to

```
com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
```